# Looping through Bootstrap tabs and creating buttons each time

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, prepared-statement

I have a products table where all the new products are inserted into. This products table contains the product name as `product_name` and the department which the product belongs to as `department`.

I am trying to iterate through my products in order to produce tabs which will contain the department title and all of the products (as buttons) which are associated to each department as the tab content.

So far, I've only managed to get to display the departments as the tab titles and the first products associated to each department.

Any help or push in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

```
  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;

  $deptData = array();
  $query = "SELECT `product_name`, `department`
  FROM `products`
  WHERE `status` = 'Active'
  GROUP BY CONCAT(`department`, `product_name`)";

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($product_name, $department);
  $stmt->store_result();

  while($stmt->fetch()) {

    $deptData[$department][$product_name]['product_name'] = $product_name;

  }
  $stmt->close();

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                <?php

                $tabTitle = "";
                $tabTitleClass = "";

                foreach($deptData as $department => $product_name) {

                   if($i == 0) {
                       $tabTitleClass = "active";
                   } else {
                       $tabTitleClass = "";
                   }

                   /* Build our tab pane title */
                   $tabTitle = '<li class="'.$tabTitleClass.'"><a href="#'.$department.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$department.'</a></li>';

                   echo $tabTitle;

                   $i++;

                } ?>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
                <?php

                    $tabContent = "";
                    $tabContentClass = "";

                    foreach($deptData as $department => $product_in_dept) {
                        foreach($product_in_dept as $product => $value) {

                            if($j == 0) {
                                $tabContentClass = "tab-pane fade in active";
                            } else {
                                $tabContentClass = "tab-pane fade";
                            }

                            /* Build our tab content */
                            $tabContent = '  <div id="'.$department.'" class="'.$tabContentClass.'">
                                                <button class="btn btn-default">'.$value['product_name'].'</button>
                                             </div>';

                            echo $tabContent;

                            $j++;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
        </div>

       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue after some more digging. For anyone who might come across this and find it useful; the answer was that only the first result was being applied the 'active in' class (from the first loop of results) and the other button was thus hidden.